# Equivalent to parameter expansion in shell script

Tags: bash

I understood parameter expansion

`a = ${b:-c}`

which will assign content of 'b' to a if 'b' is set and else content of 'c'

Is there anyway I can directly do  `a="123":-"456"` rather than storing  '123' to variable and '456' to another variable.

Comment: Huh?  If `b` is set to a constant `123`, then by definition `c` will not be needed.  Thus, your hypothetical example of `a="123":-"456"` is exactly equivalent to `a="123"`.  If you want `c` to be a constant, go for it: `a=${b:-456}` is legitimate.

Comment: Tiny correction: `a` is set to `b` if `b` is a *non-null* value; if `b=""`, then `a` will also be set to `c`.

Comment: Can you perhaps explain your desired goal a bit better? As bishop indicates if you are using a constant instead of the variable `b` in the assignment then you will **never** need the `c` variable/constant there.

Comment: @EtanReisner "123" I will replace with some expression like  echo "8u51" | cut -d 'u' -f1

Comment: Then show **that** in your question. But the answer is "no". You can't replace the initial (left-hand side) variable with anything else. The right-hand side can be anything you want though.

Comment: Sorry for creating unnecessary confusion

Answer (score 4):

> I understood parameter expansion

```
a = ${b:-c}
```

> which will assign content of 'b' to a if 'b' is set and else content of 'c'

Not exactly.  In the first place, whitespace around the `=` sign is not permitted.  In the second place, `${b:-c}` expands to the same thing as `${b}` if parameter `b` is set AND non-null.  In the third place, if parameter `b` is null or unset, then `${b:-c}` expands to the literal text `c`, not the contents of a parameter `$c`.

> Is there anyway I can directly do a="123":-"456" rather than storing '123' to variable and '456' to another variable.

The `:-` part is an aspect of parameter expansion syntax.  It is not an operator, such that you could use it in other contexts.

Moreover, what you propose doesn't make sense.  If you have a literal string then you know whether it is null, so you don't need such a construct.  However, the `c` in the expression you gave is a "word" not a variable name, so you *can* do

```
a=${b:-456}
```

to set parameter `a` to the same value as parameter `b` if `b` is set to a non-null value, or else to the string `456`.

You can do more complicated things, too, because the alternative replacement text -- '456' in this case -- is a "word" subject to expansion.  In particular, if you do want the alternative value to be the expansion of parameter `c` then you can do this:

```
a=${b:-${c}}
```